# Importing a CSV and displaying data - weird CSV layout

Tags: powershell, csv, filtering

I am trying to streamline our password reset script at work.
We have been asked to send password resets to team leads.
I am looking to get the script pull the team lead name from a CSV file.
We have an export for the team memberships (this can change across the company so we would export to a CSV once a week or so)
The problem is the format of the CSV file.

I am thinking of using the `Out-Gridview` with selection feature, but I dont want to display the whole CSV, just the team the member is part of.
I am looking for a way to search for Department (sales, service desk, HR, etc..), then Team, and finaly dislay just the team members email addresses, and another column indicating role if available (not all have that listed).

I have no issues with importing, dislaying in grid view, or returning the selected member info to the script -  it is just narrowing what is displayed.

An example is (sorry about the text layout - didn't see a table option):

```
_______________________________________________________
Department          |User ID          |Email
_______________________________________________________     
Service Desk        |                 |
_______________________________________________________
Team 1              |                 |
_______________________________________________________
                    |Member 1          |Member 1 email
_______________________________________________________
                    |Member 2          |Member 2 email
_______________________________________________________
                    |                 |
_______________________________________________________
Team 2              |                 |
_______________________________________________________
                    |Member 4          |Member 4 email
_______________________________________________________
                    |Member 5          |Member 5 email
_______________________________________________________
```

The code to select a person looks like this at the moment, but you still have to search the whole index. Oh and it looks like I forgot this at the start - I am using powershell 3.0

```
$userList = Import-Csv 'E:\users.csv'
$TeamLead = $userlist | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single
$Teamleademail = $teamlead.email
```

Basically I am looking for a way to select the group of rows following the department (say everything from Service desk to HR), and then further narrow it by teams (selecting all the rows between team 1 and 2), and then displaying just that section in the grid view.
I know the filtering would be somewhere between '$TeamLead = $userlist' and  'Out-GridView -OutputMode Single', but I cant think of a way to select the rows with empty department column information.

Thanks for any assistance with this.

Comment: Narrowing what is returned is done by piping to Select-Object. If you share your code I can show you where to include it.

Comment: How do you distinguish between department and team in the same first column?

Comment: Thats what I haven't figured out yet. sadly this is the export we get from HR, and modifying it all the time would be more work then it is worth.

Comment: The code would be along the lines of:
`code`
$userList = Import-Csv 'E:\users.csv' `code`
$TeamLead = $userlist | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single `code`
$Teamleademail = $teamlead.email
`code` ... didnt see option to enter code with out it running into 1 single line..

Comment: There is no option to enter _multiline_ code in post comments. Please [edit] your question rather.

Comment: The simple answer is that you're not really getting a file that contains the information in a machine readable manner as it lacks separators or a description. Maybe talk to HR to change it. `Team 1` is not a department, those values should be in separate columns. The empty line is unnecessary as well. As it is you could loop through the elements and look for empty values to find a new "section". `$team = ''; for($line in $userList){if($line.Deparments -eq ''){echo "we have a member for team $($team)";}else{$team = $line.Department}}`.

Comment: Are you forced to use this CSV file? Maybe you could rely on Active Directory attributes like `department` and `manager`?

Comment: sadly, that info isnt updated to AD. I wish it was, would make life so much easier. Also the data from HR is an export from the HR app they have, so no real option to change what I recieve. My current work around is to modify the CSV in excel by having it fill empty cells with the info from above if empty. Helps filter out some of the info. Trying to get powershell to do that at the moment when it loads the CSV - Less steps to get it ready for use, the less places it can break